# Ensure JSON content always loads - sometimes it fails

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I have a microsite that has a base index.html and loads in other html files with Ajax, within those loaded HTML files, I also load in content from JSON files. I was wondering if there was a way to make sure this content always loads, because I find sometimes the HTML loads but the JSON content doesn't: When user clicks to go to a new layer I call the JSON in with AJAX (loadContent()), within this function I call another function which loads in JSON content in specfic html elements (showInfo())

maybe my code isn't robust and needs touching up.

Example code:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a.loser-next-button', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#mch-overlay-content').html('');
        $('#mch-overlay-content').load("layer_recommend.html");
        loadContent();
});

function loadContent(){ 
    $.ajax({
        url: "json/" + language + "/content.json",
        data: "nocache=" + Math.random(),
        type: "GET",
        cache : false,
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(source){
            data = source;
            showStartpage(data);
            showInfo(data);
        },
        error: function(data){
            alert("Failed to load content");
        }
    }); 

}

function showInfo(){
    $(".start .text3").html(data[language]['startpage']['text3']);
    $(".start .text4").html(data[language]['startpage']['text4']);
    $(".start .text5").html(data[language]['startpage']['text5']);
    $(".start .text6").html(data[language]['startpage']['text6']);
    $(".start .text7").html(data[language]['startpage']['text7']);
                ...................................
```

Comment: 1. How is `language` set? Is it guaranteed to have a value when the request is done? 2. Why are you passing `data` to `showInfo` when the function takes no parameters?

Comment: language is set to a value such as "de", and has a guaranteed value. I pass data to showInfo to pass whatever is returned from the ajax call to that function

Comment: Well, your `showInfo` has no parameters specified, so it is completely unnecessary to pass it in the call... As to why it fails - what does the browser developer tools day about the request?